# Solve the Diophantine equation $m!n! = m!+n!$.

Tags: diophantine-equations, factorial

Find all pairs of natural numbers $(m,n)$ such that:

$m!n! = m!+n!$

I just found the solution $(2,2)$

Comment: Writing it as $1/m! + 1/n! = 1$ might be more useful...

Comment: This is not Diophantine.

Comment: Example $2!2!=2!+2!$

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Not in the strict sense (multivariate polynomial) , but nevertheless , such equations are usually considered to be Diophantine because we ask about integer solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ (m!-1)(n!-1) = 1  $$
and both factors are nonnegative integers

Comment: A nice rephrasing of the problem!